# MySQL cannot create foreign key, errors 1005, 150

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, referential-integrity

I'm trying to add a foreign key to a MySQL InnoDB table, linking a `BIGINT` with a table within the same database. I'm using MySQL Workbench to do this. It generates a script:

```
ALTER TABLE `MyDatabase`.`MyTable` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `myNewForeignKey`
  FOREIGN KEY (`TheId` )
  REFERENCES `MyDatabase`.`MyReferencedTable` (`id` )
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
, ADD INDEX `myNewForeignKey_idx` (`TheId` ASC) ;
```

When applied I get:

```
ERROR 1005: Can't create table 'MyDatabase.#sql-1ab6_5c3df97' (errno: 150)
ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.
ERROR 1050: Table 'MyReferencedTable' already exists
```

I even tried removing the table (could do that as it's empty) and recreating it with foreign keys and all, but it leads to the same errors.

I've seen reports of bugs relating to this, but they are several years old and should've been fixed by now. Surely foreign keys must be possible to add. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the SQL that Workbench produces.

Comment: Are `MyTable(TheId)` and `MyReferencedTable(id)` both `bigint unsigned` (or both `bigint signed`)?

Comment: @ypercube: Both are `BIGINT(20)` and they are unsigned.

Comment: Does `MyReferencedTable(id)` have a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint?

Comment: @ypercube: Yes, primary key in `MyReferencedTable` is the autoincrement `id` column (`BIGINT(20)`). It also has two indices, but no `UNIQUE` constraints.

Comment: Can you add in the question the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE MyReferencedTable;` I can't think of anything else.

Comment: @ypercube: My apologies, turned out the table had a MyISAM engine. Changed it to InnoDB and it worked. Your help guided me in the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I confused my databases and incorrectly thought I was working with InnoDB databases. Turns out one of them was MyISAM and then foreign keys don't work. Unfortunately, MySQL Workbench doesn't inform the user of this on Windows, but it does on the Macintosh version. (I guess it's good after all to have developers on your team with Macs.)

Hope this helps somebody with the same error message.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone encounters this problem in phpmyadmin, it could be due to the fact you have multiple identical constraints on a field. That can happen sometimes.

Check with SHOW CREATE TABLE  to obtain all constrains. In case you find duplicates, erase one of them.

Then, in phpMyAdmin, you will probably need to setup all constraints from beginning for that table.So, erase and re-create all FKs through phpmyadmin for that table.

And then, it should work.

Comment: This question already has an answer - and phpmyadmin has nothing to do with it. Nor multiple constraints. The referenced table was not InnoDB.